# Many2one field with our own function in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I need to create many2one field.but it should need to filter data as per my logic in function.It should be selectbox also.then how to implement this in OpenERP ver 7 ?

i tried with below code.But its not give a list, which i need. It just load all value from the model.And I need the first value of the select box should be get selected by default.

```
 def _sel_proj(self, cr, uid,context=None):
        cr.execute("""SELECT project.id,account.name FROM project_project project
                           LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account account ON account.id = project.analytic_account_id
                           LEFT JOIN project_user_rel rel ON rel.project_id = project.id
                           WHERE (account.user_id = %s or rel.uid = %s) GROUP BY project.id,account.name"""%(uid, uid))
        return [(r[0],r[1]) for r in cr.fetchall()]

 _name  = 'mat.mgmt'
 _columns = {'project_id':fields.many2one('project.project','Project',selection=_sel_proj,select=True,required=True),}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set project_id is many2one and remove selection attribute from field definition. You can make it selection from xml by using widget="selection" attribute on that field.

To get one value in default, you need to make default function for that, add your logic over there and return its first value by using result[0]. Call this function from _defaults in py like this:

```
def _get_project(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        #ADD YOUR LOGIC
        return result[0]

'project_id': _get_project
```

And to show the limited records as per your logic, If possible, you can convert it into domain and add the domain on project_id field from xml like this

```
domain="[('analytic_account_id.user_id','=',uid)]"
```

Comment: but in my function i am joining three tables two of which contain the users, can I create a domain for the above query ?

Comment: Yes, you can create! Is there any relation from project to project_user_rel I mean From project class, can you access it ? I did the same for analytic account as I can find analytic_account_id is a many2one in project but is it anything for project_user_rel from project so you can access it?

Comment: yes project table contain all projects and analytic account table contain the corresponding project's manager and project_user_rel contain the project members this is the logic, in the select box i want to show all projects of a particular project member(it may be project manager or project user)

Comment: domain="['|',('RELATION_ID.uid','=',uid)('analytic_account_id.user_id','=',uid)]" 
Here RELATION_ID means the field that is many2one with project_user_rel, defined into project.project. So you can access it like this. You need to replace RELATION_ID with your field label defined in project class for project_user_rel.

Comment: I have given domain="['|',('id.uid', '=', uid), ('analytic_account_id.user_id','=',uid)]" but it shows 'AssertionError: Invalid field 'id.uid' in domain term ('id.uid', '=', 1)'

Comment: analytic_account_id is many2one to analytic account defined in project.project object the same way, which relational field, you are using to show relation between project.project and project_user_rel from project.project object ?

Comment: id is the relation field between project.project and project_user_rl

Comment: 'user_rel_id': fields.many2one('project.user.rel', 'Project User Rel')
domain="['|',('user_rel_id.uid','=',uid)('analytic_account_id.user_id','=',uid)]‌​"
Use it with this name and try again.

Comment: I have added this but this shows an error like this '('Programming Error', 'There is no reference available for project.user.rel')'

Comment: what is the object name of project_user_rel table that you used in left join ?

Comment: there is no object created for the model project.user.rel. This model is created using project object like this 'members': fields.many2many('res.users', 'project_user_rel', 'project_id', 'uid', 'Project Members',)

Comment: Ohh, I think so for that, you need to fire query. With simple domain, it will not work. If you need to check only one condition regarding analytic account, then its possible to use with domain.

Comment: query can execute only through function, but that is not working also , as specified in my question

Comment: As I specified in my answer, to get first value in default, You need to create default function for that. To filter data so you can show it in selection, for that, you need to override search method of project.project by passing any context and base on that context, fire the same query and return list of project ids.

Comment: can you help me , how to override the search function?

Comment: You can take example of project module, project.py file , line no 82.

Comment: I have tried to override search function see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578933/error-occured-while-overriding-the-search-function-of-a-class-in-openerp

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

```
'project_id': fields.selection(_get_project, 'Select Supplier'),
```

Comment: Add a some explanation to this answer for the OP.