# Error occured while overriding the search function of a class in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I tried to override search function of class 'project' to filter the projects.But its not give a list, which i need. It just load all value from the model . From where I need to pass the context.Below given is my code

```
class project(osv.osv):
_name = "project.project"
_description = "Project"    
_inherits = {'account.analytic.account': "analytic_account_id",
             "mail.alias": "alias_id"}

def search(self, cr, user, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
    if user == 1:
        return super(project, self).search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=count)
    if context and context.get('user_preference'):
            cr.execute("""SELECT project.id FROM project_project project
                       LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account account ON account.id = project.analytic_account_id
                       LEFT JOIN project_user_rel rel ON rel.project_id = project.id
                       WHERE (account.user_id = %s or rel.uid = %s)"""%(user, user))                
            return [(r[0]) for r in cr.fetchall()]
    return super(project, self).search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order,
        context=context, count=count)

_columns = {
            'members': fields.many2many('res.users', 'project_user_rel', 'project_id', 'uid', 'Project Members',
        help="Project's members are users who can have an access to the tasks related to this project.", states={'close':[('readonly',True)], 'cancelled':[('readonly',True)]}),

         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it from xml code. It should be many2one with project.project and add the context like context="{'test': 'yes'}" in xml file where you define this field like this:

```
<field name="project_id" context="{'test': 'test'}"/>
```

By overriding search method of project.project, check this context. Now you should get this context in search method.

If you get this context, fire your query, get the result accordingly it and return it as list of ids. If you don't get, return super method of project.project as specified in the code. Also, remove the condition of if user==1 as per your need, you do not require it otherwise it will come up with all list of projects.

Comment: I have added the fields like this 'project_id':fields.many2one('project.project','Project',context="{'test': 'yes'}"),  then cheked the value of 'context' in the function serach like this   'if context and context.get('test'):'  inside this executed the query and return the value but still all values are listing

Comment: Can you check by printing context at the top of search means are you getting 'test' in context or not and inside your if condition that is checking context? If your flow goes into inside of if loop ?

Comment: No, context value is not getting inside the function I tried to print it on the top of the function but nothing printed

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it. You need to pass it from xml code where you add that field in form view. Also, you need to remove that condition if user == 1. If you will not remove it, it will also come up with all projects.

Comment: I have done as you suggest but not working ,actually i have a doubt, is the overriding function name is search or _search . If i give function name as _search it load correct values but if go to the project module section then infinite loop will execute and code will break

Comment: Did you update the module after adding context from xml? Are you getting that context in print of search method ? Is it going inside your context if condition ? Did you remove that user ==1 condition?  yes method name is correct, its search.

Comment: yes, I have done everything you said, context value is not getting inside the function. I am try to do this on another way please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578570/many-to-one-relation-not-working-in-fields-selection-in-openerp  is this posibile

Comment: Something goes wrong at your end. The way I suggested to you, by that way, it should work. You should get the context in search method.

Comment: Regarding that link, you posted, it will not work if you want to link it with object. by simple, it should work without any relation. I thing, that format is also wrong. There should not be any attribute like relation, type=many2one, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks priyesh I got answer using domain filter which you have given, I have made a small change in it and it is working thank you so much for your valuable help